# Importing a Gradle Project (libGDX) in Eclipse Photon

Tags: eclipse, gradle, java-8, libgdx, eclipse-photon

nothing I have found so far helped me. I am trying to Import a Gradle Project (libGDX Project to be exact) into Eclipse Photon but the only thing I get is the following : [image]

On my other Notebook everything worked fine. On this one here I have JDK 8 installed. Does anyone know what's going on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I tell you what I think is wrong, have a good look at the error message. Eclipse is basically telling you it tried to find something, in this case a plugin, and couldn't.

As the error message says, you need to install the gradle gwt plugin in order to import gradle projects. To do this, open up the plugin market place, search for "gradle gwt", (in general) download the most popular one, and follow the installation process.

I hope this answer helped you! If you have any other questions about this answer, feel free to leave a message below.